# Best way to implement Events on Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

As a .NET developer, I'm accustom to delegates and event on custom controls. I have been creating javascript codes for quite sometime but I'm wondering the best way to implement this in javascript. Below is how I normally code my components.

```
var RGComp= RGComp || {};
RGComp.MyComponent = function () {
    function events(){
        $("a").unbind("click");
        $("a").click(function () {
             // Do something
        });
    }
    function generateUI(){
        //generate HTML UI
        events();
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is improper. I have to call unbind all the time to avoid clogging up the DOM. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? What do you mean by "clogging up the DOM"?

Comment: Nowadays you leave that up to the framework (React, Angular, Vue ...)

Comment: Note if you're actually doing something like `$("a").unbind("click");` which gets every `a` element you could accidently unbind events setup in some other piece of code. Note once an element is destroyed so is the event handler's connection, ie the function will no longer be called. And if you are worried about "clogging" you could use event delegation to minimize the number of event handlers setup

Comment: @PatrickEvans, what do you mean by event delegation?

Comment: @AndreNuechter, I noticed that without the unbind, the whole page become unresponsive. So I'm assuming just doing .click just add the event listener without checking if it exist in the DOM.

Comment: @JonasWilms, it might sound stupid but I'm trying not to use other framework to because I would like to learn javascript ins and outs. In addition, relying on 3rd party framework means that if there's issue found with it our solution will be stuck,

Comment: Event delegation is putting a single event listener on some static parent (one that doesnt get removed) and from that listener delegate actions based on what element triggered the event. [Can read more here](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: There isn't a best way to handle events in JS I'd say. And on a side-note, if you want to learn JS in and out, you should drop jQuery ;)

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks for the link. Looks like this is what I'm looking for however, will it work on elements that has been added on the fly? I mostly develop single page applications without frameworks. so normally I will have one div and change the content of the divs on the fly.

Comment: Yes that is one of the primary reasons for using event delegation

Answer (score 0):

## Global Event Handlers

There are going to be folks for and against anything including the movement of air-molecules though at the end of the day all that matters is that you're able to do what you need to do and you stay organized in the process. On the JAB Creations web platform we use global events where appropriate and on occasion we set *element specific* events *if necessary*.

```
//Do not shorten event to e, you WILL want to reference e separately.
window.onclick = function(event)
{
 if (condition) {}
 else if (condition) {}
}
```

Setting specific events:

1. Generally you'll want to check if the `section()` or `page()` is appropriate (presuming you have proper information hierarchy).
2. You'll want to have a function return the current page's id, in my case this is `push_current_id()` or `id_(push_current_id())` (e.g. `push_current_id() == 'admin_'` for the control panel and before the character limitation lift for the `id` attribute in HTML5).
3. Setting static events for specific elements is okay in a few circumstances though often you'll want to have universally applicable behaviors:

## CTRL + Horizontal Scrolling:

```
window.onwheel = function(event)
{
 if (event.ctrlKey)
 {
  if (e.scrollHeight > e.clientHeight && event.deltaY != 0)
  {
   event.preventDefault();
   //Change 5 to adjust sensitivity.
   e.scrollLeft = e.scrollLeft + (5 * event.deltaY);
  }
  //else if (condition) {}//Other behavioral tweaks.
 }
 //else if (condition) {}//Other behavioral tweaks.
}
```

The main take-away is that you're limiting most if not all of your event calls to the global handlers and you can be as specific or broad in the conditions required for an element to hook in to parts of those global events. You won't need to add/remove events, just adjust your `if` conditions. I'm sure someone out there will harshly disagree though we've had nothing but success with this approach on an entire web platform designed to work explicitly in the absence of frameworks and libraries to maximize performance.

Comment: Thanks @John, on my example generateUI actually adds html elements on the fly. Will global event handle elements that has been added on the fly?

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian I only work with the XML parser which is strict (the HTML parser is drunk and naked at your wedding "relaxed"). You need to properly `importNode`/serialize code before porting it to the DOM. I just don't know how it is handled by the HTML parser though with the XML parser weird stuff happens like `id` not being understood. The nice thing is that when you do everything right in HTML5+XML it's ridiculously solid. For a good example go to https://www.jabcreations.com/docs/javascript/ then click on `xml_add` function and double-click the code (another global tweak).

Comment: The parser has nothing to do with event delegation(which is what this is). As long as the event that the element triggers (wither or not the element was added dynamically) is set to bubble up the dom (as most are) and propagation was not stopped with stopPropagation it will cause the set handler to be called.